# innerHTML closes tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following switch structure:

```
switch (ratio) {
  case "16:9":
    imgContainer.innerHTML = '<img src="images/test-rata-de-aspect.jpg">'       
    break       
  case "4:3":
    imgContainer.innerHTML = '<img src="images/schita-usi-2.jpg">'
    break
  default:
    imgContainer.innerHTML = '<img src="images/schita-usi-1.jpg" usemap="#schita-usi-1">'
    imgContainer.innerHTML += '<map name="schita-usi-1">'
    imgContainer.innerHTML += '<area shape="rect" coords="191,108,577,973" href="test.html"  alt="" title="">'  
    imgContainer.innerHTML += '</map>'
    break    
}
```

What we need to look at is the `default` case.

The code works fine but the `<map>` tag is closed before containing the `<area>` tags.

I did some research and it seems that it might be caused by badly formatted HTML. Also tried to create a variable that contains the  code and then calling that variable like this:

```
var htmlcode = '<img src="images/schita-usi-1.jpg" usemap="#schita-usi-1">';
var htmlcode += '<map name="schita-usi-1">';
var htmlcode += '<area shape="rect" coords="191,108,577,973" href="test.html"  alt="" title="">';
var htmlcode += '</map>';
imgContainer.innerHTML = htmlcode
```

This variant generates an error in the console: SyntaxError: missing ; before statement on this line: `var htmlcode += '<map name="schita-usi-1">';`.

I'm pretty novice when it comes to JavaScript. I don't see any HTML errors in the code, what would be the problem here? What causes the `<map>` tag to autoclose in this case?

Let me know if I need to provide further details.

Comment: because that is what it does... You are not building a string, you are appending to the DOM and the parser corrects your html markup closing the tags. If you want to build a string, build it and than append it when you are done. You did that correctly, but your error is simple typo by including `var` on each line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right path.  The reason this behavior was happening in the first place is that once you set that HTML of the live DOM element on the page, the browser is going to try to "correct" any broken HTML for you.  This includes closing tags.

As you intend, the solution is to put all of your strings together *first* and *then* set the result to the HTML of the element.  But in your attempt at least one problem is that you're trying to re-declare the same variable over and over.

You don't really need the variable.  You can simply build the string all on one line of code and set it to the HTML.  Something as simple as this:

```
imgContainer.innerHTML = '<img src="images/schita-usi-1.jpg" usemap="#schita-usi-1">'
                       + '<map name="schita-usi-1">'
                       + '<area shape="rect" coords="191,108,577,973" href="test.html"  alt="" title="">'  
                       + '</map>';
```

That gives you the multi-line formatting you want in the code (I assume for readability), but performs the entire operation as a single assignment.  Everything to the right of the `=` will be evaluated first (all of the "lines", even though until the semi-colon it's all one "line of code"), and then the result is assigned to the left of the `=`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the subsequent `var` keywords after the first line so it becomes:

```
var htmlcode = '<img src="images/schita-usi-1.jpg" usemap="#schita-usi-1">';
htmlcode += '<map name="schita-usi-1">';
htmlcode += '<area shape="rect" coords="191,108,577,973" href="test.html"  alt="" title="">';
htmlcode += '</map>';
```

After you have declared a variable with `var`, don't use the `var` keyword again for the same variable.

Comment: well you can, not good practice... just can't do it with += :)